# Spring\JPA\PostgreSQL: Why do I get a table I didn't create?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a spring boot for the first time.
I am using Spring boot version 2.3.4.
I also use PostgreSQL.
I wanted to create two tables: Player and Team.
The team should have a list of players.

So I created the next two Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Players")
public class Player {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int dateOfBirth;
    
    private String originCountry;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
    private Team team;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Teams")
public class Team{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="team_id")
    private Long teamId;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "team", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList();

}
```

As you probably already know, spring boot created the tables automatically.
The problem that the Team table doesn't have the players column\s.

What is wrong here?
Maybe I don't need to see the players columns in the Team table? (which seems strange to me...)
Is there a better way to define a list or array of values?

Also, I want to understand: does `@JoinColumn(name="team_id"))` defined the column name of Player's team property `private Team team;`?

Thanks!!

Comment: The `@ElementCollection` annotation, if indicated, is mapped by a collection table. See docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html#:~:text=Annotation%20Type%20ElementCollection&text=Defines%20a%20collection%20of%20instances,means%20of%20a%20collection%20table.)

Comment: @blurfus Right. But removing the annotation didn't change a thing.

Comment: The DB Table is already created (it creates it the first time if it does not exist) - you would need to delete the table yourself from the DB

Comment: let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: @blurfus Thank you for your patience. It did not help. I also tried to use OneToMany annotation as you can see in the question but had similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two different concepts when you think about object-relational mapping (ORM). Remember you are using JPA and, behind the scenes, Hibernate. One thing is your objects for the `Java` application, another is the set of tables you have, for example, think about a `Many to Many` relation alone. You can map it easily with 2 objects:

```java
class Match {
...
    private Set<Team> teams;
...
}

class Team {
...
    private Set<Match> matches;
...
}
```

That's a many-to-many composition of two objects. But how can you map it on a normalized relational database? You need a `Junction Table` in this case, so you will have the two tables plus a `team_match` table which will have only the id of a team and the id of a match and both fields will be a unique constraint. Therefore, when you want to fetch the information you will use a `JOIN`, like this:

```sql
SELECT t.*, m.* FROM team t
  JOIN team_match tm ON t.id = tm.team_id
  JOIN match m ON m.id = tm.match_id
```

What happen is that the framework, in this case Hibernate, abstracts all of this translating the objects into tables. And, sometimes, it will not be one object to one table exactly.

With that in mind, thinking about relational databases, you will always need that extra table. You can achieve that in Postgres using a `jsonb` type, but I would not recommend in this case, so I will not write more about it. Nevertheless, I recommend you to dive deeper reading about ORM (object-relational mapping) to understand better what will happen behind the scenes. And hope the answer helps you.

**EDIT:**

Ok, sorry, your comment made me realize that I could show you the way to achieve that. So, the most canonical way of doing that would be something like this:

```java
@Entity
class Team
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="team_id")
    private Long teamId;

    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL)
    private List<PlayerId> players;
    // ...
}

@Entity
class PlayerId {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private Long playerId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
    private Team team;
    // ...
}
```

Note that the `@OneToMany` annotation references the object composed in the target entity. Hope it helps.

**EDIT 2:**

About the `@JoinColumn`: the `name` is the join column in the current table/entity and the `referencedColumnName` is the join column in the foreign table/entity.

Comment: Thank you! Should it really be that indirect? All I need is a table (object) which contains a list of other objects (also entities mapped to a table). I didn't think the solution should be so tortuous... I would be happy to know how you would implement it. A team of players. The teams are stored in "teams" table and players skills are is "player_id" table. Thank a lot!

Comment: Well, I think my answer is missing that, right? I'm editing it and will add it. As a `OneToMany` relation does not demand a `Junction Table`. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: thanks. What is the value "id" for referencedColumnName ? Is it the player id or the team id?

Comment: I made some updates to the code above. Can you check please what do I do wrong?

Comment: Well, the Javadocs explains better than I, so: `(Optional) The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column`. More here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html